# When to use or not to use "no" before a noun phrase

Tags: word-usage

While comparing and contrasting various aspects of English and German one thing I come across is this: "No" indicates denying or refusing something, thus:

> "Is John here?" 
>  "No."

But "no" is also used in this sense:

> He has no money left.

In German, the first "no" above is "nein", and the second is "kein".

However, "kein" in German is used distinctly more frequently than "no" in *that* sense is used in English. In particular, a German whose English is fairly good wrote "Spiders are no insects." where I would have written "Spiders are not insects." And his usage seems to match the sort of context in which I would expect "kein" to be used in German.

My question is how to explain to someone like that when to use "no" in the second sense above, and when to use "not" or some other locution.

Comment: The software told me I could not use "No things" as the subject line because it is too short.

Comment: Think about it this way, `no = not any`. Anywhere you feel comfortable to use `not any`, you should be able to use `no`.

Comment: I don't think that rule, Elgs, words very well.

Comment: Another example: In a story written in the 1950s, several thousand new immigrants to a colony on a planet where, it seems, salt is a moderately scarce commodity are served lunch just after they arrive. On each table there is a small sign that says "Don't waste the salt." In a published translation of the story into German, it says "Vergeudet kein Salz." In English one wouldn't say "Waste no salt." unless the emphasis were different.

Comment: . . . . and in English one says "She doesn't like fruit." and not "She likes no fruit."

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that we do not normally use the quantifier "no" in the complement of a copular verb (such as *be*, *become*, *seem*).

The question of why German does this and English does not, like most "why" questions about language, is not really answerable: it just is that way.

[There is one common exception: with a specific subject, and when specifically denying something that has already been stated or assumed. This often occurs in the punchline of a joke, such as *That was no woman: that was my wife!*]

Comment: Good Heavens, Colin!. The joke is: "That was no lady, that was my wife."

Comment: Actually the reason why German uses "kein" in that way seems clearer if one looks at further examples of how that word is used, so it's somewhat more "answerable" than I have made it appear. But that leaves the question of how to explain to the German what the English usage is.

Comment: @J.Taylor: you're right. Oops

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the answers already given, there's the *[no-versus-not](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/no-or-not)* usage that English provides (condensed summary follows):

> *No* and *not* are the two most common words we use to indicate negation.
>   We use *no* before a noun phrase. We use *not* with any other phrase
>   or clause.
>
> We often use *no* to respond to a yes-no question, or to agree with a
>   negative statement. We don’t use *not* on its own in this way.
>
> When a noun has an ungradable meaning (it is either something or it is
>   not) we cannot use no + noun
>
> When a noun has a gradable meaning, *no* + noun means the same as *not*
>   a/an + noun.

There are many other rules in the article, some of which are summarized in the other answers, but *nein*/*kein* usage seems to roughly mirror *no*/*not* usage.

But to return to your examples:

> "Is John here?" "No." (Answer to yes/no question.)
>
> He has *no* money left = He has *not any* money left (Money is
>   gradable; you can have more or less of it.)
>
> Spiders are *not* insects. (*Spider* is ungradable; it's an insect, or
>   it's not.)

Comment: You say "We use no before a noun phrase." But that doesn't explain why one says "Spiders are not insects." rather than "Spiders are no insects."

Comment: _Ach_, I missed that example. Added.

Answer (score 0):

*Spiders are not insects* is the "unmarked" or matter-of-fact form, used in everyday English, when the writer is just stating a fact. This will be the much more frequently used form.

Another example: *Whales ares not fish; they are mammals*.

The use of *no* in the first sentence

*Spiders are no insects* can be seen as a more vehement statement of the fact. Or a strong denial, as when a witness in a court case might say about the accused

*That man is no gentleman; he is a criminal of the utmost degree*.

In this, the denial that the accused is a gentleman is strong and allows for no exceptions, as it were, as an utterance taken on its own.

Based on your example of *he has no money*, the difference here includes the fact that *money* is (in this context, and usually) a *mass* noun; whereas your original question and examples, and my examples, all deal with count nouns, either singular or plural (recall that *fish* is the standard plural of *fish*, although *fishes* is sometimes used).

This answer intends to cover your original examples, and I haven't the time to extend it to cover other examples, such as mass nouns and difference in syntax of what exactly is being negated.

Comment: So it's _only_ a matter of emphasis?

Comment: In the sentence "He has no money left.", it seems as if no way of expressing with "not" would be as short and simple as that sentence. And likewise with the word "no" before the word "way" in the foregoing sentence. So this makes it appear that there is something other than emphasis that can be an occasion for using the word "no" in that sense.

Comment: It is certainly a matter of emphasis, and communicatice function, based on situational context. As for *he has no money*, well, *money* is a non-count noun, so that's different from the plural forms *spiders*, *fish*, and the singular form *criminal*.